# How do I get rid of this and other fugitive bloatware on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bloatware

I connected my digital camera to my new HP dv7 laptop and Snapfish came up and offered to move all the photos to the pc and to their service. This tells me that Snapfish is installed at least to some extent. However, I could not find it in the start menu or in Control Panel's Uninstall list. I did find it by the "search programs and files" box in the start menu.

How can I remove this and any other fugitive programs that might be lurking around sucking up my system's resources.

Answer (score 3):

HP is notorious for preloading crapware.

Try these:

- http://www.ehow.com/how_5806046_remove-snapfish-computer.html
- http://www.ehow.com/how_6783472_uninstall-snapfish.html
- http://www.justanswer.com/computer/33c88-completley-remove-snapfish-computer-canceled.html

---

> #### Removing Snapfish
>
> 1. Restart your browser. Do not open Snapfish.com again until the steps are
>    completed.
> 2. Click "Tools" in Internet Explorer.
> 3. Click "Internet Options."
> 4. Click "Settings" in the "Temporary Internet Files" section.
> 5. Click "View Objects" in the Settings dialog box.
> 6. Right-click on "Snapfish File Upload ActiveX Control," and click
>    "Remove."
>
> Now, to ensure that the toolbar won't
> automatically reinstall, yo need to
> clear your browser cache and temporary
> Internet files.
>
> #### Clearing the Browser Cache
>
> 1. Click "Tools" at the top of the Internet Explorer window.
> 2. Click "Internet Options."
> 3. Click "Clear History" in the "General" tab.
> 4. Click "OK" when it asks "Delete All Items in Your History Folder?"
> 5. Click OK.
>
> #### Clear Temporary Internet Files
>
> 1. Close all instances of Internet Explorer.
> 2. Click "Start."
> 3. Click "Control Panel."
> 4. Click "Internet Options."
> 5. Click "Delete Files" under "Temporary Internet Files" in the
>    "General" tab. Ensure that the check
>    box for "Delete all offline content"
>    is checked, and click "OK."

Answer (score 1):

[PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/). Guess what it does :-).

Comment: This looks good, yet it did not find the Snapfish program I'm trying to get rid of.